# Software for planning schedule

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-one, schedule

I'm looking for schedule planning software.

I'd like to be able to add weekly events, meetings that repeat every month etc., and I expect the software to display me a schedule for the upcomming week, as well as short notes attached to planned activities.

It would be great if it could synchronise my planned events via UbuntuOne.

What are your recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **[Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar)** with my Google account from any browser or platform available. I can have several calendars (e.g. work, school, family) tagged by colors. The events can be single or repeating and can integrate with other Google apps, such as sending email reminders. You can also share your schedule as full details or busy/not busy and view other shared schedules on top of yours.

I've been using Google Calendar from Chrome, Firefox, (Ubuntu) and Safari (OS X), all work fine.

Comment: I like the synchronization possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

**[Evolution](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)** is -no doubt- the solution for you. It syncs the calendar with Google services and certain services with Ubuntu One (like the Contacts). Unfortunately it seems that Ubuntu One doesn't provide support for syncing calendars yet.

Evolution's calendar provides enough tools for continuous/recursive and/or repeating scheduling. You can include as many local/remote calendars as you wish, which includes but not limits only to Google Calendar. Evolution's daily/weekly/monthly/yearly report will solve your needs for a schedule preview.

If you are used to MS Outlook in Windows based systems, you will feel comfortable when using Evolution.

Evolution provides the same functionality as Outlook for Email/Calendar/Contacts/Notes/Tasks, etc.

Evolution syncs perfectly with certain mobile devices/PDA's which makes the portability of your data an easy task. I am -in example- using my Palm Tungsten E2 for syncing my Evolution data which syncs Calendar, Contacts, Notes and Tasks. (Palm Tungsten E2 doesn't provide support for eMail).

You can find Evolution in the Software Center and install it in a click. Tell us how are you doing with this task and don't hesitate to drop back a comment if you need further assistance.

Good luck!

Comment: I'd prefer software dedicated to scheduling tasks instead of Outlook-like application that manages my mails & contacts too.

Comment: Let's wait for somebody else to drop a good choice for your needs, but if you find it before please drop an answer/comment in order to follow up your solution. Thank you and... Good luck!